# Constant states do not match in developer preview android L

Tags: android, resources, imageview, equals, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to do something in an if-statement, this works in every version of android (16 or higher because of the getDrawable) except Android L (tested on latest). The code is the following:

```
if (item.getIcon().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_to_fav_normal).getConstantState())
```

Any help/hints or explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: and? i don't see any question mark here?

Comment: My questions if not clear: How come? How to fix? Alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `item.getContext().getDrawable(int)` or the equivalent [`ContextCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html) method.

Starting in API 21, all framework widgets that load drawables use [`Context.getDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable(int)) which applies the context's current theme during inflation. This basically just calls `getResources().getDrawable(..., getTheme())` internally, so you could also use `context.getResources().getDrawable(..., context.getTheme())`.

```
     if (item.getIcon().getConstantState().equals(item.getContext()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.add_to_fav_normal).getConstantState())
```

In general, though, you shouldn't rely on this check. There are no API guarantees around what constant state you'll receive from a particular drawable.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation: "There are no API guarantees around what constant state you'll receive from a particular drawable." - This wasn't an issue for previous api's (as I know) yet, but I have rewritten the code so that this particularly check isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Where did you read "There are no API guarantees around what constant state you'll receive from a particular drawable"? I haven't found the documentation backing it, tho it's definitely changed from previous APIs

Comment: I am the framework engineer who owns the API. In general, if it's not an explicit public API or a documented behavior (or tested by CTS) then it's not guaranteed to be the same across different versions, or even within a single version across different devices.

Comment: It worked fine for me with just a little edit:  item.getIcon().getConstantState().equals(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery).getConstantState());

Answer (score 0):

This solution is convenient for tests only:

```
public static void assertEqualDrawables(Drawable drawableA, Drawable drawableB) {
    Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableA).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableB).getBitmap();
    ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap1.getHeight() * bitmap1.getRowBytes());
    bitmap1.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer1);

    ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap2.getHeight() * bitmap2.getRowBytes());
    bitmap2.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer2);

    Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(buffer1.array(), buffer2.array()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @alanv's answer, below is what I did and was successful:

```
if (imgClicked.getDrawable().getConstantState()
                    .equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,
                            R.drawable.add_profile).getConstantState())) {

     //Both images are same

}else{

    //Both images are NOT same      

}
```

Thank's @alanv :)