# Drag and Drop doesn't work properly in some devices

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I created a simple drag-and-drop game app where user need to drag a card from stack and drop it into correct category slot. My problem is when I tested the app in three devices, two device passed the test but one device failed. The problem for this one device is, the category slot won't accept the card eventhough the card is correctly dragged into correct category slot. The result in the logcat returned `false` instead of `true`.

```
02-01 21:13:03.219 25955-25971/com.theothercard.dragdrop I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7750(606KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(12KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 10MB/11MB, paused 11.205ms total 47.587ms
02-01 21:13:03.459 25955-25955/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=192, x2-x1>=192, x3-x2>=192, x4-x3>=182, x4-x0<=749 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x4-x0<=749. 
02-01 21:13:18.059 25955-25955/com.theothercard.dragdrop I/ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false
02-01 21:13:21.139 25955-25955/com.theothercard.dragdrop I/ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false
02-01 21:13:30.119 25955-25955/com.theothercard.dragdrop I/ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false
```

Here is the code for drag and drop mechanism inside `GameActivity()`

```
 public boolean onDrag(View receivingLayoutView, DragEvent dragEvent) {

    final ImageView draggedImage = (ImageView) dragEvent.getLocalState();
    final ViewGroup draggedParentLayout = (ViewGroup) draggedImage.getParent();
    final FrameLayout bottomLayout = (FrameLayout) receivingLayoutView;

    // stop the timer when all cards dragged into correct place.

    if(topLayout.getChildCount() == 1) { // only empty card left
        timer.cancel();
        complete = true;

        // disable skip button because it has no use anymore
        skipButton.setEnabled(false);

        // add summary to database
        Player p = new Player(name, Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), seconds, score);
        insertRecord(p);

        // victory!
        victoryDialog();
    }

    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            if (dragEvent.getClipDescription()
                    .hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            String category = "";

            switch (bottomLayout.getId()) {

                case R.id.asetSemasa:
                    category = "AS";
                    break;
                case R.id.asetBukanSemasa:
                    category = "ABS";
                    break;
                case R.id.belanja:
                    category = "B";
                    break;
                case R.id.cost_of_sales:
                    category = "COS";
                    break;
                case R.id.ekuitiPemilik:
                    category = "E";
                    break;
                case R.id.hasil:
                    category = "H";
                    break;
                case R.id.liabiliti:
                    category = "L";
                    break;
            }

            boolean result = placeCard(draggedImage, draggedParentLayout, bottomLayout, category);
            return result;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

            if (!dragEvent.getResult()) {
                draggedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return true;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is the method definition for `placeCard()`

```
protected boolean placeCard(ImageView draggedImage, ViewGroup draggedParentLayout,
                            ViewGroup bottomLayout, String cardCategory) {

    for (int card = 0; card < Card.cards.length; card++) {
        // compare dragged image reference is similar as one of the card image reference.
        if (draggedImage.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(
                getResources().getDrawable(Card.cards[card].getCardResId()).getConstantState())) {
            if (Card.cards[card].getCardCategory().equals(cardCategory)) {
                draggedParentLayout.removeView(draggedImage);
                //bottomLayout.removeAllViews();
                //bottomLayout.addView(draggedImage);
                bottomLayout.setBackground(draggedImage.getDrawable());
                draggedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                scoreText.setText(String.format("Score: %s", Integer.toString(score += Score.rightScore())));
                wrongCount = 0;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    scoreText.setText(String.format("Score: %s", Integer.toString(score -= Score.wrongScore())));
    wrongCount++;
    if(wrongCount >= 3) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Wrong three times, skip to next card...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        skipNextCard();
        wrongCount = 0;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and here is my `game_activity.xml` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/pw_repeating"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Score: 0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0:00"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/start"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/reset"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/quitBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/quit"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:src="@drawable/emptycard"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/skipBtn"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/skip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        grid:rowCount="4"
        grid:columnCount="4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        app:rowOrderPreserved="false"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        app:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/aset_semasa"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/aset_bukan_semasa"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/belanja"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="@string/cost_of_sales"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/asetSemasa"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/emptycard">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/asetBukanSemasa"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@drawable/emptycard">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/belanja"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@drawable/emptycard">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ekuitiPemilik"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/emptycard">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/hasil"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@drawable/emptycard">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/liabiliti"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@drawable/emptycard">

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/ekuiti_pemilik"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/hasil"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/liabiliti"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/cost_of_sales"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_column="3"
            android:background="@drawable/emptycard" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I really have no idea what to do now. I appreciate all the help from you.

**Additional Information:** The device I tried and getting successful results are Redmi Note 3 Pro running Marshmallow, and Galaxy Note 8.0 running Marshmallow. The failed one is Zenfone 5 running Lollipop.

**Update:** Since I'm comparing between two ConstantState to get correct image, here is the logcat.

Testing using Redmi Note 3 running Marshmallow:

```
2-01 21:55:30.616 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.616 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@8b65297
02-01 21:55:30.617 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.617 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@a955c84
02-01 21:55:30.617 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.617 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@5e0cc6d
02-01 21:55:30.617 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.618 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@84e70a2
02-01 21:55:30.618 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.619 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@f038133
02-01 21:55:30.620 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.620 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@64dbcf0
02-01 21:55:30.620 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.621 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@4ac269
02-01 21:55:30.621 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.621 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@d46f4ee
02-01 21:55:30.622 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.622 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@b55d916
02-01 21:55:30.624 11714-11714/com.theothercard.dragdrop I/ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: true
```

Testing similar image, using Zenfone 5 running Lollipop:

```
02-01 21:58:11.908 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:11.918 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@2d5b7e1e
02-01 21:58:11.918 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:11.938 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@33cdccc
02-01 21:58:11.938 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:11.958 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@15bd5e2a
02-01 21:58:11.958 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:11.978 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@13c0f9b8
02-01 21:58:11.978 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:11.998 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3aab32f6
02-01 21:58:11.998 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:12.018 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@c67f964
02-01 21:58:12.018 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:12.038 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@fcf8882
02-01 21:58:12.038 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:12.058 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@e5d47d0
02-01 21:58:12.058 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:12.078 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@26f1aace
02-01 21:58:12.078 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:12.088 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@201710fc
02-01 21:58:12.088 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:12.108 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@1501a5da
02-01 21:58:12.108 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/DRAGGED IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@3d9aef58
02-01 21:58:12.138 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop D/ORIGINAL IMAGE: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@174240e8
02-01 21:58:12.138 25079-25079/com.theothercard.dragdrop I/ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false
```

The main concern here why the latter does not have any similar ConstantState, or I am doing it wrong.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I solved the problem by referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768973/2783365). Just change

```
 if (draggedImage.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(
            getResources().getDrawable(Card.cards[card].getCardResId()).getConstantState())) {}
```

to

```
if (draggedImage.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(GameActivity.this, Card.cards[card].getCardResId()).getConstantState())) {
```

in `placeCard()` method.

Basically starting from API 21, you have to use `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` instead of normal `getResources().getDrawable()` method.